# Spotlight: mds_stores using IMPORTANT IO priority for background index, slowing computer down

Tags: spotlight, performance

I've been having a problem where the UI will start lagging (mouse moving jerkily, video not playing smoothly, etc.) on an intermittent basis. It seems a lot of the time like `mds_stores` is running at a high CPU usage. Sometimes, Spotlight will show that it's indexing as well.

I'm interested in why it seems to be having such a large effect on my system when it should be a background task. Lo and behold, when I run `sudo taskinfo mds_stores`, I get the following output:

```
process: "mds_stores" [55561] [unique ID: 1245849]
architecture: x86_64
coalition (type 0) ID: 325
coalition (type 1) ID: 326
suspend count: 0
virtual bytes: 38.27 GB; phys_footprint bytes: 57.75 MB; phys_footprint lifetime maximum bytes: 109.96 MB
run time: 81 s
user/system time    (current threads): 75.067131 s / 27.259428 s
user/system time (terminated threads): 57.942725 s / 21.024646 s
interrupt wakeups: 11900 (768 / 6.45% from platform idle)
default sched policy: POLICY_TIMESHARE
CPU usage monitor: 50% CPU over 180 seconds
CPU wakes monitor: 150 wakes per second (over system-default time period)
dirty tracking: tracked  dirty
boosts: 0 (0 externalized)
requested policy
        req apptype: TASK_APPTYPE_DAEMON_INTERACTIVE
        req role: TASK_UNSPECIFIED (PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE_DEFAULT)
        req qos clamp: THREAD_QOS_UNSPECIFIED
        req base/override latency qos: LATENCY_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED / LATENCY_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED
        req base/override thruput qos: THROUGHPUT_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED / THROUGHPUT_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED
        req darwin BG: NO
        req internal/external iotier: THROTTLE_LEVEL_TIER0 (IMPORTANT) / THROTTLE_LEVEL_TIER0 (IMPORTANT)
        req darwin BG iotier: THROTTLE_LEVEL_TIER3 (THROTTLE)
        req managed: NO
        req other: passive-int
        req suppression (App Nap) behaviors:
effective policy
        eff role: TASK_UNSPECIFIED (PRIO_DARWIN_ROLE_DEFAULT)
        eff latency qos: LATENCY_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED
        eff thruput qos: THROUGHPUT_QOS_TIER_UNSPECIFIED
        eff darwin BG: NO
        eff iotier: THROTTLE_LEVEL_TIER0 (IMPORTANT)
        eff managed: NO
        eff qos ceiling: THREAD_QOS_USER_INITIATED
        eff qos clamp: THREAD_QOS_UNSPECIFIED
        eff other: passive
imp_donor: YES
imp_receiver: NO
pid suspended: NO
adaptive daemon: NO (boosted: NO)
```

In particular, `eff iotier: THROTTLE_LEVEL_TIER0 (IMPORTANT)` looks worrisome. I *don't* want `mds_stores` to run at the same IO priority as my regular processes.

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to change the IO priority of an already-running process. There is the [setiopriority_np(3) system call](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/setiopolicy_np/), but that only lets you change the IO priority of the current process.

I've even tried looking at the launch agent I'm pretty sure is responsible for `mds_stores`, `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.index.plist`:

```
{
  "_ExponentialThrottling" => 1
  "CFBundleIdentifier" => "com.apple.Spotlight"
  "EnableTransactions" => 1
  "EnvironmentVariables" => {
  }
  "HardResourceLimits" => {
    "NumberOfFiles" => 2048
  }
  "Label" => "com.apple.metadata.mds.index"
  "LowPriorityBackgroundIO" => 1
  "MachServices" => {
    "com.apple.metadata.mds.index" => 1
    "com.apple.metadata.mds.index.xpc" => 1
  }
  "POSIXSpawnType" => "Interactive"
  "ProgramArguments" => [
    0 => "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds_stores"
  ]
  "SoftResourceLimits" => {
    "NumberOfFiles" => 2048
  }
}
```

On the one hand, I see `"LowPriorityBackgroundIO" => 1`, but on the other hand, there is `"POSIXSpawnType" => "Interactive"`. Has anyone else had luck in replacing the System mds_stores launchd configuration with one of your own, where I could change `"POSIXSpawnType" => "Interactive"` as well as may launch the job with `taskpolicy`?

System: Monterey - macOS 12.4, Intel

I don't have any Time Machine backups indexed (I don't even have Time Machine on this computer):

```
mdutil -a -s
/:
    Indexing enabled.
/System/Volumes/Data:
    Indexing enabled.
```

Comment: I also have an Intel MBP (2019) running on macOS Monterey with no Time Machine. It also suffers from mds_stores once every few days taking too much CPU time for extended periods of time, immediately slowing down the MBP, rendering all Spotlight functions nearly ineffective, and causing fans to run at full speed. I deleted and rebuilt Spotlight indices twice but did not help. Excluding the Parallels (Windows) directory from Spotlight indexing did not help either. The only partial solution I could find was restarting the MBP which seems to solve the problem at least for a few days every time.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same in your case but my MBP is plugged in to an electrical outlet most of the time and the mds_stores gets hyperactive at times only when my MBP is plugged in and when I am actively using it. Fortunately, the mds_stores never gets hyperactive when my MBP is running off of the batteries. Hope you get some good answers to your question.

Comment: @Alper I also have an Intel MBP (2019) with Touch Bar, and it's plugged into an electrical outlet most of the time, so that would match your circumstances. I'm thinking of disabling System Integrity Protection one of these days and editing com.apple.metadata.mds.index.plist to try to force it to run at throttled priority, but if it boosts its own priority when plugged in, that would be trickier to fix.

Comment: I had another episode of hyperactive mds_stores today after having no such problems for nearly ten days. No idea what triggers it. My MBP was connected to an electrical outlet as usual. I switched it to batteries to see if this would somehow naturally stop or slow down mds_stores but it did not. While the fans got silent initially, per the battery settings I reckon, the computer kept getting hotter and eventually the fans started running wild again. I restarted the computer and things got back to normal as usual. I plan to write to Apple about this via their feedback page.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this problem? I have been continuing to have the same problem with my MBP which requires me to restart it at least once or twice every week, also same as before. Sometimes, I need to restart even twice or more consecutively. Upgrading to macOS Ventura did not help either.